# Последовательное чтение нескольких файлов

Tags: python

в соседней папке есть список нескольких файлов, представляющих собой таблицу с данными(данные записаны списком в 4 столбика "значение, цена, вес, количество", и мне нужно эти данные оттуда взять, и между собой сравнить, чтобы найти в каждом файле самый "дорогой" и самый "дешевый" пункт. Пробовал вот такой код, чтобы получить возможность к информации в каждом файле, но он не работает

```
import os

path = '/Users/folder/' # некая папка, в которой лежат несколько файлов
path_normalized = os.path.normpath(path) 
for dirpath in os.walk(path_normalized): 
    print('')
x = 0
while True:
    print(dirpath[2][x]) # здесь я получаю список названий файлов, и пытаюсь перебрать по номеру элемента
    x+=1
    handle = open("/Users/folder/"+dirpath[2][x]+"r") # пытаюсь подставить в ссылку название файла, чтобы потом прочитать
```

Каким образом можно последовательно добраться до информации в файлах, чтобы ее можно было дальше обработать?

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? Что этот код вообще должен делать?

Comment: Я таким образом пытаюсь открыть последовательно файлы, генерируя к каждому путь до него

Comment: Ну и? Не открывается или в чем проблема?

Comment: Да, такой метод получения ссылки очевидно неправильный. Поэтому хочу узнать ответ от людей, кто уже сталкивался с такими задачами, каким образом они делают

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что неправильный? Почему вы думаете, что этот код не работает?

Comment: Во-первых, как уже заметил @Эникейщик, распишите, как именно не работает Ваша программа. Выдаёт какие-то ошибки? Просто закрывается и ничего не делает или что? Во-вторых, пройдитесь отладчиком и посмотрите, какие пути у Вас получаются в переменной. Ну или хотя бы используйте `print`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
def open():
        price_scope = []
        with open(folder, mode='r') as open_ticker:
            for element in open_ticker:
                scattered_element = element.split(',')
                name_ticket = scattered_element[0]
                if scattered_element[2] != 'PRICE':
                    price_scope.append(float(scattered_element[2]))
            return price_scope```
````